# auto pick schema change of underlying table for view

Tags: sql-server

I know that the sql server doesnt pick the schema change of underlying table. for example, if we execute the following,

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id INT)

CREATE VIEW viewa
AS
SELECT *
FROM tbl

ALTER TABLE tbl ADD NAME INT
```

and execute a select on view, only ID column is returned

```
SELECT *
FROM viewa
```

Is there any property I can set by which the sql engine autopicks the schema changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `sp_refreshview` for this,

```
exec sp_refreshview N'dbo.viewa'
```

Comment: "dbo.tbl" is table name. you should specify view name in place of table name

Comment: Thanks Abdul. But is there any server level property we can set to auto pick those even if we forget to execute the proc? something like I created view with select * from tbl. Even if I dont run any procs, I need to see all columns by setting some property like 'set nocount ON' etc

Answer (score 1):

There's no out of the box functionality for this.  But you could roll your own.  The [system tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176106.aspx) detail all the columns currently attached to each view and table.

```
-- Returns every column for the given table/view.
SELECT 
    c.* 
FROM 
    sys.objects AS o
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s     ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
        INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c     ON c.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE 
    s.name = 'MySchema'
    AND o.name = 'MyTable'
;
```

You would need to create a control table that maps your tables to views.  You would also need to schedule the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can create view with "SCHEMABINDING" option. That way base table definition cannot be modified in a way that could affect view definition.

```
CREATE VIEW viewa
AS
SELECT *
FROM tbl SCHEMABINDING
```

Comment: Thanks Akshey. But the requirement is that I can update table but all dependents with select * should auto pick new columns